# `fontawesome` icons ignored when knitting Rmarkdown to PDF

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, pdflatex

Unfortunately, I fail to knit an *.Rmd file in RStudio to PDF that includes `fontawesome`-icons. However, when knitting to `output: html_document` in renders perfectly.

Info:

- I am using R version 4.0.3 with RStudio 1.3.1056
- I have installed the latest [TeX Live](https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html) distribution

The following example contains elements taken from [RStudio's Github](https://github.com/rstudio/fontawesome):

**Icon renders in HTML:**

````
---
title: "FontAwesome in R Markdown"
output: html_document
---

```{r load_packages, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, include=FALSE} 
library(fontawesome)
```

This is an R icon: `r fa("r-project", fill = "steelblue")`.
````

**Icon is ignored for PDF output:**

````
---
title: "FontAwesome in R Markdown"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r load_packages, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, include=FALSE} 
library(fontawesome)
```

This is an R icon: `r fa("r-project", fill = "steelblue")`.
````

Neither R nor Rmarkdown shows any errors when rendering to PDF. Does anyone have an idea why it does not work?

Thank you very much.

Cheers,
Christian

Comment: Can you add `keep_tex: true` to your header and show the intermediate .tex file?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz In the .tex file `r fa("r-project", fill = "steelblue")` seems to be ignored as well. Anything else (e.g. `r rnorm(1)`) is working though. [See .tex file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R_VRG6Ev5k7Hr4aCmy1Tj8ztIxsDfTGP/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: For the pdf output, you could add `\usepackage{fontawesome5}` in your header includes and then use `\faRProject` in the document.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks for this workaround. It works but rather than altering the .tex file I'd like to make use of the `fontawesome` package in Rmarkdown, if possible.

Comment: You don't need to alter the .tex file, you can do this from within the rmarkdown file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can workaround the problem by using the `fontawesome5` latex package:

```
---
title: "FontAwesome in R Markdown"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{fontawesome5}
---

This is an R icon: \faRProject
```